# C# - how to write a collection (Dictionary?) with one key and two values

Tags: c#, dictionary, collections

What's the easiest way to create a collection of key, value1, value2 ?

Important to me is that it is easy & short to retrieve either value1 or value2 given the pair (please show an example)

I know I can do this -

```
class MyObject
{
    internal string NameA { get; set; }
    internal string NameB { get; set; }
}


class Other
{
    Dictionary<string, MyObject> MyObjectCollection { get; set; }

   private void function()
    {
        MyObjectCollection = new Dictionary<string, MyObject>()
            { { "key", new MyObject { NameA = "something", NameB = "something else" } } };                
        var valueA = MyObjectCollection["key"].NameA; // = "something"
    }
}
```

Is there a better way?

Comment: you can have a dictionary with key and a List of values `Dictionary<string, List<string>> MyObjectCollection { get; set; }`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

The solution which is easiest to *implement* (`Dictionary<String, Tuple<String, String>>`) is not the one which is easiest to *support* and *develop* (what is `MyObjectCollection[key].Value2`?). So I suggest using *your own class*:

```
  class MyPair {
    public string NameA { get; internal set; }
    public string NameB { get; internal set; }

    public MyPair(nameA, nameB) {
      NameA = nameA;
      NameB = nameB;  
    }

    public override String ToString() {
      return $"NameA = {NameA}; NameB = {NameB}";
    }
  }

  class Other {
    // you don't want "set" here
    // = new ... <- C# 6.0 feature
    public Dictionary<string, MyPair> Data { get; } = new Dictionary<string, MyPair>() {
      {"key", new MyPair("something", "something else")},
    };

   ...

 Other myOther = new Other();

 String test = myOther.Data["key"].NameA;
```

Comment: Thanks, accepted your answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use a [Tuple](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.tuple(v=vs.110).aspx):

```
Dictionary<string,Tuple<string,string>> MyObjectCollection {get; set;}

private void function()
{
    MyObjectCollection = new Dictionary<string, Tuple<string,string>>();
    MyObjectCollection.Add("key1", Tuple.Create("test1", "test2"));               
}
```

Comment: Are there any benefits vs. using a custom class aside from the few lines of code saved?

Comment: @OryZaidenvorm Not really, I only use them internally because they're easier than defining a struct/class for everything. I wouldn't recommend exposing a Tuple as end result

Answer (score 0):

```
List<MyObject> list = new List<MyObject>();
var res = list.ToDictionary(x => x, x => string.Format("Val: {0}", x));
```

The first lambda lets you pick the key, the second one picks the value.